# How do you input a vim command that begins as `:25y ...`

Tags: vim

I'm looking at https://www.vimgolf.com/challenges/513b1dcd2d1ae10002000010 and trying to input the answer but it goes into command mode. I'm unfamiliar with the notation that begins with `:25y`.

Comment: It's supposed to go into command mode.

Comment: This particular command is `:y`, so start by looking at `:help :y` and notice it will take a `[count]` (like most commands in Vim will!) Kudos on using VimGolf! That's a great way to improve your Vim skills.

Comment: Also, you might want to check out the [Vi & Vim StackExchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) for questions on Vim.

Answer (score 1):

As @hobbs has mentioned, this is part of an Ex command (sometimes termes colon command).

This is all a part of vim’s legacy as an improvement on vi, which is a visual interface for ex, which is a much improved ed.

**I cannot emphasize enough how helpful it is to understand this legacy.** It is not "bad" in the sense of « legacy code »—rather, it’s part of what makes vimmers productive editors, and the targets of some jealousy (no flame wars, emacs friends).

However, getting to know this legacy can often wait until one is familiar with the vim fundamentals<sup>1</sup>. Knowing about `:` is one of those, though. I recommend running `vimtutor` and then `:help` just to get started. To enter `:help`, you type `:help`<kbd>Enter</kbd> from Normal mode.

1. Some, of course, consider `ed` to *be* vim’s fundamentals. I’m among that group, but I didn’t learn vim that way, so I don’t usually recommend it. `ed` can be frustrating to get started with, but an experienced vimmer can feel relatively at home, and make at least quick productive edits in a pinch. Imagine a system with no editor! But `ed` is required by POSIX, so all is not lost...